# How does React work under the hood when we refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

**React newbie here**

I know that we don't need to refresh (`ctrl R`) the browser whenever I do a change on my local react file. I can just save the file and the browser will automatically render any changes.

How does react **work under the hood** to achieve this? what is happening in the background when I save my local file? Does my local nodejs server listens to this event somehow then calls react's render function?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading.html

Comment: That's actually not React per se. If you created your app using create-react-app, then it's using webpack-dev-server to reload the app on save. You can use webpack-dev-server, and a number of other hot reloaders completely independently of React.